# Can I copy the remote folder of node mudules on git lab?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

The node module that I need has been updated, and there is an old version of it installed on the gitlab project. Is it possible to get the folder for that specific module as it is when it was installed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You dont't want to keep source code of external dependencies in your repo. You should add your node_modules to .gitignore and remove it from the repo. Instead, you just track your dependencies in your package.json file by installing them via `npm install --save`. Then, when someone checks out your project, he just runs `npm install` and all dependencies get resolved automatically. If you want to update any of the dependencies, you update it via npm cli, and commit the updated package.json to your repo.

Comment: I am having a problem in the build, one of my branches works, the other branch, after building it breaks, they have the same code. I would like to literally paste the dependencies to see if the problem comes from there

Comment: Try using Yarn instead of NPM. It will create a special package.lock file, which will include complete determining information about all the dependencies, including file hashsums. That wil guarantee that each install of your project is exactly same.